# php,MySQL: how to display SELECT COUNT WHERE results?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show results of a 'SELECT COUNT' with clause 'WHERE' on display, and I don't know if it is a syntax issue or not; here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utenti WHERE surname= 'Smith'";
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array was deprecated 2500 years ago. Try to avoid mixing APIs - especially with deprecated ones.

Comment: Is there any error message given when running that code?

Comment: no, there's only blank display

Comment: Has it been 2494 years already, @Strawberry? How does the future look? ;-)

Comment: @Qirel Bleak :-(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use deprecated API MySQLi
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Try to use PDO instead https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM utenti WHERE cognome = 'Tosone'"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Mysqli is not deprecated

Comment: two days lost to find the exact syntax...and I still can't

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) AS nb FROM utenti WHERE surname= 'Smith'")) {
    $res = $result->fetch_assoc();

    print_r($res["nb"]);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP has a column called `cognome`.

Comment: So I edited my answer...